# python: replace string based on the input provided

Tags: python

var1 variable has the output below:

```
    Name: prod
    Default Network: Yes
    VLAN ID: 2
    Operational VLAN: SWA
    Config Qual: N/A

    Name: dev
    Default Network: No
    VLAN ID: 3
    Operational VLAN: SWA
    Config Qual: N/A
```

If `VLAN ID = 2`, I want to replace `Name` with`prod1`, and if `VLAN ID = 3`, I want replace `Name` with `dev1`.

This is to achieve question [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43635708/python-to-handle-text-file-to-print-its-output)

Comment: what format of variables is? json?

Comment: you'd have to be a little more specific on what are you trying to achieve how is the VlanID 2 related to the "1" that must pe added to the name and so on, and by the rules of the site you should explain what you've tried and what it failed

Comment: @TitanFighter seems like it's a string ...  output from some remote shell/CLI of some router

Comment: @LohmarASHAR, ah... I see... Seems you are right.

Comment: I want to replace string so that  i will provide input to other purpose..i struck here

Comment: @LohmarASHAR, Just added more info

Comment: so you want to change the line `Name: prod` into `Name: prod1` 
or from `Name: prod`  to `prod1: prod` ? (that's what I've intended)

Comment: no, Name: prod to prod1: prod and Name: dev to dev1:dev